# How to relay several video feeds from one network to another?

Tags: networking, apache, network-administration

I have to supply video feeds from one network to another with a different IP Addressing system (one is class B, with subnet mask 255.255.0.0 and the other is C; 255.255.255.0). They are on the same physical switch but can't communicate naturally, to my knowledge, without IP conflicts.

One network has a few dozen CCTV cameras, while the other has several hundred nexus 7 (2013) tablets that will always be on and connected. We need to be able to have the user pick a camera feed to watch.

We had the idea to 'funnel' all the data from the cameras to a PC/server and then dispatch it then on. The nexus's would have no idea what each camera's IP address is or that the camera even exists. The idea is that the PC would constantly take the UDP feeds and then, on demand by the nexus tablets, replicate and dispatch the feeds to as many devices that call for it.

The only real question is that this is all theoretical and we have no idea what software we should use for this type of thing. I've heard about Apache and started to learn a bit of it, but I'm not sure that it would work for this. I would be willing to learn how to use Apache but am unwilling to waste time learning it just to find out that it won't serve my needs.

So does anyone have any experience with this type of thing? Could you please point me to the right direction as which type of software we should use?

It needs to be able to constantly take video input from several sources and essentially cache them for a small while. It also needs to take requests from the nexus tablets. For example, Nexus #7 might ask for Camera #3's feed. The nexus doesn't know the IP config of the camera and the camera isn't aware of the nexus. But the server needs to know the proper subnets (if any) and IP addresses of both types of devices and be able to relay the feed from one camera to one or more tablets.

Thanks in advance.